# Can direct antennas used to route a localized CommNet network to a long-range destination if the vessel also has relay antennas?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I understand relay antennas are used to relay and direct antennas aren't, but direct antennas can call home and are more light-weight than relays. I was thinking of the following system:

[image: A light-weight direct relay on top for calling home, 4 small relays for local communication.]

The idea is that I'd like to put this satellite on different planets, and use the small relays to connect with other near-by vessels. My hope is that the other vessels will be able to access the main CommNet through this satellite's direct antenna, even though it's not a `relay`. Will it work?

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at Remote Tech 2 Mod for KSP? Currently its an _alternative_ to existing stock CommNet, but it works as you would expect in description above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wondered the same myself, but came to the conclusion that it won't work.  I believe this is (more or less clearly) documented in the in-game KSPedia, and of course it's also reasonably easy to test.

I finally had some time to actually run such a test.  The test craft I used consisted of two probes:

- Probe 1 had a single Communotron 88-88 antenna (antenna power 100G, direct only), and two HG-5 relay antennas (antenna power 5M each, relay capable).
- Probe 2 only had two Communotron 16 antennas (antenna power 500k each).

These probes were launched together into a solar orbit and, once sufficiently far from Kerbin, separated.  After undocking the two probes, and setting them to float right next to each other, the results were as expected:

**Probe 1: 100% signal strength (direct connection to Kerbin)**
[image: Screenshot]

**Probe 2: 23% signal strength (relayed through probe 1, using only the HG-5 antennas)**
[image: Screenshot]

Just to check, I closed the 88-88 antenna on probe 1, and observed its signal strength also drop to 23%:

[image: Screenshot]

Repeating the same test further out, beyond the range of the twin HG-5 antennas, probe 2 could not get any signal at all, while probe 1 (with the 88-88 antenna open) still had 100% signal strength.

Indeed, [the wiki also confirms this behavior](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/CommNet#Connections_through_Relays), stating that:

> [...] if a different vessel is connecting through you to communicate with the KSC the Direct Antennas are disregarded in any calculations made.

Comment: Since you weren't able to test, it, I decided to set it up myself using cheats. Sure enough, it doesn't work. What a shame!

Comment: It does feel unrealistic, but I guess it's a reasonable tradeoff for game balance. The stock CommNet abstracts away so many other details of relay satellites (like the need to aim them, or even to have multiple antennas on each relay, or the huge amounts of power they should need) that there needs to be *some* extra challenge to compensate, and apparently what the devs chose for that challenge is having to launch a bunch of heavy and bulky relay antennas. In any case, given how easy it is to launch a relay sat more powerful than the level 3 DSN, I can't really complain about it being too hard.

Comment: Ps. I finally managed to test this myself, and added some screenshots to my answer.